# Using a dynamic string containing apostrophes in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to find a way to use a submitted string in MySQL that may contain apostrophes.

```
$user = $_POST["user_name"];
$userf = $_POST["firstname"];
$userl = $_POST["lastname"];
$userg = $_POST["gender"];
$userc = $_POST["city"];
$users = $_POST["state"];
$userd = $_POST["description"];
$usert = $_POST["tagline"];
$useri = $_POST["icon"];
$userm = $_POST["mobile"];
$userh = $_POST["home"];
$userb = $_POST["bdate"];




$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_icon`=$useri,`user_first`=$userf,`user_last`=$userl,`user_tagline`=$usert,`user_mobile`=$userm,`user_home`=$userh,`user_desc`=$userd,`user_city`=$userc,`user_state`=$users,`user_gender`=$userg,`user_bdate`=$userb WHERE `user_name`=$user";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

When I submit the following array:

```
Array ( [user_name] => WyattC [firstname] => Wyatt [lastname] => ------- [gender] => Male [bdate] => 03/27/1999 [city] => Bend2 [state] => OR [description] => For those who accidentally stumbled on to my site, you are probably wondering who I am. Well... That would be a great question to ask me, except I don't know. On the surface, I'm a 17 year old teenager with brown hair, and brown eyes who likes to do random things that he finds entertaining. [tagline] => I am a potato. [icon] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/-gHt0jnZzg1Y/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/_qw8fD-Hz7Y/s100-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg [mobile] => ---------- [home] => ---------- )
```

I get a series of errors. How can I fix my query?

Comment: just use prepared statements instead, then you don't need to find a way the check whether the user inputs an apostrophe

Comment: prepared statements?

Comment: or you can use htmlspecialchars http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: yes prepared statements. It has both PDO and Mysqli, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: how would i use htmlspecialchars in my code? @daremachine

Comment: Don't use htmlspecialchars for this.  It has nothing to do with SQL and will not protect you from SQL injection.  There are *other* escaping methods that can work, but prepared statements are the safest and best.